# Is pattern recognition a measure of spatial IQ?

Tags: iq

Does pattern recognition come under spatial IQ, or is spatial IQ only to do with mental rotations and visualising?

Comment: If it's a 3D pattern, yes, if it's only a 2D patters, no.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but you might want to look at the most widely accepted framework for organising cognitive abilities: The Cattell–Horn–Carroll theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattell%E2%80%93Horn%E2%80%93Carroll_theory

In this model speeded rotation is situated under visual processing. 
But you'd have to check what is meant by perceptual speed.

[image: subset of cattell horn carroll]

In my thesis, I measured Cube Comparison (which is a kind of mental rotation task) along with several common measures of perceptual speed (speed of comparing, sorting numbers, and finding numbers in a set) and I found that cube comparison tended to load on both perceptual speed and general ability factors.
http://cogprints.org/8035/7/anglim-2011-skill-acquisition-phd-thesis.pdf

[image]